# Neo4j load CSV to create dynamic relationship types

Tags: neo4j

I can load CSV into Neo4j for a specific label (say `PERSON`) and the nodes are created under the label `PERSON`.

I also have another CSV to illustrate the relationships between the person and it looks like:

```
name1, relation, name2
a, LOVE, b
a, HATE, c
```

I want to create a relationship between these pairs and the relationship thus created should be "LOVE", "HATE", etc, instead of a rigid `RELATION` as done by the below script:

```
load csv with headers from "file:///d:/Resources/Neo4j/person-rel.csv" as p
match (a:PERSON) where a.name=p.name1
match (b:PERSON) where b.name=p.name2
merge (a)-[r:REL {relation: p.REL}]->(b)
```

By doing this, I have a bunch of `REL`-type relations but not `LOVE`- and `HATE`-relations.

In another word, I want the `REL` in the last line of the script to be dynamically assigned. And then I can query out all the relationship types using Neo4j API.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can install the [APOC library](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures) and then use `apoc.merge.relationship`

> apoc.merge.relationship(startNode, relType,  {key:value, ...}, {key:value, ...}, endNode) - merge relationship with dynamic type

```
load csv with headers from "file:///d:/Resources/Neo4j/person-rel.csv" as p
match (a:PERSON) where a.name=p.name1
match (b:PERSON) where b.name=p.name2
call apoc.merge.relationship(a,p.REL,{},{},b) yield rel
return count(*);
```