# Loading a entity relation triple csv as nodes

Tags: csv, neo4j, neo4j-apoc, triples

Suppose I have a csv file with data in the format (`Subject`, `relation`, `Object`).

Is it possible to load this into neo4j as a graph modeled such that the subject and object become nodes and the relation between them is the relation from the triple? 
Essentially while loading from the csv, I want to load the subject and object as individual nodes and the relation is the one joining them.

```
(subject)-[:relation]->(object)
```

My csv is in the format
ent1,state,ent2
a,is,b
.
.
.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Neo4j load CSV to create dynamic relationship types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47808421/neo4j-load-csv-to-create-dynamic-relationship-types)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, It's possible. You need to install the [APOC plugin](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures) in Neo4j and then use `apoc.merge.relationship`.

**Refer the following query to load the data:** Add/Modify required details in the query.

```
LOAD CSV FROM "file:///path-to-file" AS line
MERGE (sub:Subject {name:line[0]})
MERGE (obj:Object {name:line[2]})
WITH sub, obj, line
CALL apoc.merge.relationship(sub,line[1],{},{},obj) YIELD rel
RETURN COUNT(*);
```

Comment: I get this error when I ran this " Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError: Variable `line` not defined (line 6, column 34 (offset: 171)) "CALL apoc.merge.relationship(sub,line[1],{},{},obj) YIELD rel" ^". Keep getting the same variable not defined error every time

Comment: Can you share your query here?